# Host name and domain name purpose

Tags: linux, networking, slackware

Is there any purpose of the domain name set during Slackware installation (by `netconfig` utility) if the computer isn't going to be used as a server? If i'm right that the computer name & domain name isn't relevant if the computer acts as client (for eg. requests HTML pages or SSH server) becouse the server adresses the asking client just by it's IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how Slackware organizes things, but in general the hostname is used for example in DHCP requests (so your home router will you the name of your computer associated with its MAC address), and the domain name is used as default for all DNS lookups (HTML pages, SSH server, ...), so you can abbreviate it for other machines in your home network.

**Edit**: Here's how it works in more detail. If you set the hostname to `abc`, on initialization your computer will broadcast "Hello, I'm `abc`, is there anyone out there who can tell me where I am?" Then your home router, who runs both the DHCP server and a DNS forwarder, answers "Hello `abc`, here's your IP address, netmask, and gateway (that's me). You are in domain `uvw.xy`, and I'm also your DNS server."

It *doesn't* send the names of all computers back, or something like this. It also doesn't change `/etc/hosts` in any way.

Then your home router enters the name `abc` together with the IP address it just assigned into its database, where there are also similar entries for `def` etc. Now if *any* computer does a DNS lookup in domain `uvw.xy`, e.g. if `abc` looks up `def.uvw.xy`, it will get the local IP address. If there's a DNS lookup with a different domain, your home router forwards that to your ISP's DNS server.

There are variations on this theme, e.g. (1) the client doesn't get the domain name via DHCP, but has to set it locally, (2) the client didn't set the hostname locally, but gets it via DHCP from a MAC database in your home router (that's how it also works on bigger installations), (3) your home treats any DNS lookups without a domain name as if they were in domain `uvw.xy`, etc.

Comment: So if i understand right that the dhcp server upon client request can send back not only the propossed IP address but also domain name for the LAN and other computer names in the LAN? Based on this info the asking host then adds apropriate records in /etc/hosts file and can then adresss LAN neighbours by name instead by IP addesss?

Comment: Sort of. See edit for details.

Comment: Thx for detailed answer:-) So am i right that DHCP server can send back only  domain name and hostname of the client in answer (that is if host1 asks the server returns only host1 hostname, say abc)?

Comment: Can You please answer my last comment?

Comment: The options that DHCP can send back are described in [RFC2132](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2132) starting in section 3. There's dozens of options, but only one hostname (3.14) and one domainname (3.17).